# C++ LNK 2019 Error with templates/classes

Tags: c++, templates, lnk2019

So this part of the code is a small part of a large project. I can't copy the entire project but it's really just 2 lines making the error. I'm trying to access the function "mergeSort" from the class Metrics. Metrics is a different class than the one I'm trying to access it in. I've defined mergeSort and also #included Metrics in the class I'm working with. I've also defined the constructor. Here is the piece of code:

```
void Document::createHashWords()
{
    Node* heads[97];

    string* allWords = parseWords();
    int numWords = getdWordCt();

    for ( int i = 0; i < numWords; i++ )
    {
        char* word = (char*)allWords[i].c_str();
        int k = hashWord(word,97);
        insertWord(heads,k,allWords[i]);
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < 97; i++ )
    {
        Node* temp = heads[i];
        int size = 0;

        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            size++;
            temp = temp->getNext();
        }

        int* countArr = new int[size];
        temp = heads[i];

        for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        {
            countArr[i] = temp->getCount();
            temp = temp->getNext();
        }

        Metrics <int> toSort;
        toSort.mergeSort(countArr,size);

    }
}
```

the Code that is causing the problem is the last 2: Metrics toSort and toSort.mergeSort(countArr,size);.

Here is the Metrics class:

```
template <class T>
class Metrics
{
private:
    int id;
public:
    Metrics();
    ~Metrics();
    void selectionSort(T *arr, int n);
    void insertionSort(T *arr, int n);
    void merge(T *a, int numA, T *b, int numB, T *c);
    void mergeSort(T *arr, int n);
};
```

I've defined mergeSort in the .cpp file for that class.

Here is my build error:

```
1>Document.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Metrics<int>::Metrics<int>(void)" (??0?$Metrics@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Document::createHashWords(void)" (?createHashWords@Document@@QAEXXZ)
1>Document.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Metrics<int>::~Metrics<int>(void)" (??1?$Metrics@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Document::createHashWords(void)" (?createHashWords@Document@@QAEXXZ)
1>Document.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Metrics<int>::mergeSort(int *,int)" (?mergeSort@?$Metrics@H@@QAEXPAHH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Document::createHashWords(void)" (?createHashWords@Document@@QAEXXZ)
1>C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CMPSC 122 Checkpoint 2\Debug\CMPSC 122 Checkpoint 1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

If I remove those 2 lines, I can compile fine. I just don't know why those 2 lines are wrong. I need to access that function from the Metrics class.

```
    template <class T>
    class Metrics
    {
    private:
        int id;
    public:
        Metrics<T>() {}
        ~Metrics<T>() {}
        void selectionSort(T *arr, int n);
        void insertionSort(T *arr, int n);
        void merge(T *a, int numA, T *b, int numB, T *c);
        void mergeSort(T *arr, int n);
    };
```

So this is now my Metrics class:

```
    template <class T>
    class Metrics
    {
    private:
        int id;
    public:
        Metrics() {}
        ~Metrics() {}
        void selectionSort(T *arr, int n);
        void insertionSort(T *arr, int n);
        void merge(T *a, int numA, T *b, int numB, T *c);
        void mergeSort(T *arr, int n);
    };
```

I commented out the definitions of the constructor/destructor in the Metrics.cpp file like so:

```
    //template <class T>
    //Metrics<T>::Metrics()
    //{
    //}

    //template <class T>
    //Metrics<T>::~Metrics()
    //{

    //}
```

And now this is my error code:

1>Document.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Metrics::mergeSort(int *,int)" (?mergeSort@?$Metrics@H@@QAEXPAHH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Document::createHashWords(void)" (?createHashWords@Document@@QAEXXZ)
1>C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CMPSC 122 Checkpoint 2\Debug\CMPSC 122 Checkpoint 1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: You don't need `<T>` in the class. So just `Metrics() {}`, etc.

Comment: I did that as well just now. I added what my current metrics class is

Comment: And now your errors are different. You probably have the same issue with the other functions.

Comment: "I've defined mergeSort in the .cpp file for that class." That's your problem. Template functions need to be defined in the header file. [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?: Template implementations not visible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574417/902497).

Answer (score 0):

The missing symbol seems to be the default ctor for Metrics, the one that takes no arguments. Have you defined it? You need to get it included somehow in the same translation unit. The usual way would be to define it in the header file:

```
template <typename T>
Metrics<T>::Metrics() {}
```

Comment: Yeah. I did Metrics::Metrics() {}

Comment: In the Metrics.cpp file, though, right? I'm guessing that you didn't include that in the Document .cpp file.

Comment: I included #include "Metrics.h" in my Document.cpp file. is that what you mean?

Comment: The usual way would be to put the definition in your .h file. You don't do that for non-template functions, but you do for template definitions. (You could in theory also include Metrics.cpp in your Document.cpp, though I wouldn't recommend that stylistically.)

Comment: What do you mean? Where do I add that? In the Document.h file?

Comment: Oh. So do I put it as a public variable just as if its a Metric class?

Comment: Put `template <typename T> Metrics<T>::Metrics() {}` in your `Metrics.h` file.

Comment: I did what you said but it still doesn't work. I added my Metrics.h file above in my post

Answer (score 0):

Template functions need to be defined in every translation unit (.cpp) they're used in, so you want all of `Metrics`' member functions to be defined in `Metrics.h`, as if they were all inlined.

They work differently from normal functions because the code generated is different for every different type used for `T`, so the compiler can't know what versions to generate when compiling `Metrics.cpp`.

Comment: So do you want me to also define the Metrics constructor in the Document cpp file?

Comment: If it's defined in `Metrics.h`, and `Document.cpp` contains `#include "Metrics.h"`, then it's effectively already there. `#include` just does a copy/paste at compile time, there's no magic to it.

Comment: I have that as well though.